# How to assign values to class level properties in constructor using Object Destructuring in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object-destructuring

I am using Typescript for my react project. Thus I am passing props in the constructor.
I want to break "props" in the constructor and want to assign it to class-level variables.

This is my code  -

```
abstract class IProps{
abstract type:'text'|'checkbox'|'radio';
abstract value?: any;
abstract name?: string;
abstract id?:string;
abstract onClick?: ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent>) => void);
abstract onChange?:((val: any) => void);
abstract classnames: string;
abstract placeholder?: any;
}
interface InputProps extends IProps{
    isvalid?: boolean;
}

export class Input extends Component<InputProps>{

    isvalid: boolean|undefined=true;
iProps: IProps|null = null;

constructor(props: InputProps){
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
    const {isvalid, ...iProps} = this.props;
    this.isvalid = isvalid;
    this.iProps = iProps;        
    }
}
```

these statement in the constructor works for me.

```
 const {isvalid, ...iProps} = this.props;
    this.isvalid = isvalid;
    this.iProps = iProps;
```

But I want to assign values without using the `const` statement. I want to do something like this -

```
{isvalid: this.isvalid, ...iProps: this.iProps} = this.props;
```

How to assign values like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it starts with a `{`, you need to tell the parser that it's an expression, not the beginning of a block, by wrapping it in `()`:

```
({isvalid: this.isvalid, ...this.iProps} = this.props);
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4BJWsAVxgAUcwAZzgBvKnDjBBANxQAbYABMAXHABGECHNS0KlCYNxIYACzoBzAKJzBSVbS4g1jPQF8qVNHJSDhlgB4o4NpwSP4MtIrCyOgwAHQAwriQtEj0ADwc3HwCggB8ouKSMvJKqhpaOnoSwPwQQqq8KLDA8pmcPHVCBQC8oq6kcAD0Q3DpPRNwAOrAphA8cKZSADSLJqw+gsDmtCBp8HRrrGgQtIIwUFwY0EUSd-cPj09PI3DmxsIA7iYo8LZIIGEMAg6g2tFCUBwqXmwkYOCgcBQGgWFwAnhZbs8sdjHq9gXAuLZJF1hM5MNBWLMAOTCOizVoKABeSEURROZwuV2BUAAFGBcqosp1cgBKMT6O6CLhgRh80XVO48kRSWQKFRrKRxFWlRSrOL6paCLUk1xwPqGuL8+qCEUK9yUVxAA) -

```
class Example extends React.Component<InputProps> {
  isvalid: boolean;
  iProps: Partial<InputProps> = {}; // <=== Without the `= {}`, the assignment in
                                    // the constructor gets what seems to be an
                                    // erroneous error about trying to use iProps
                                    // before it's initialized
  constructor(props: InputProps){
    super(props);
    ({isvalid: this.isvalid, ...this.iProps} = this.props);
  }
}
```

Here's a simplified JavaScript version you can run here on SO:

```js
class Example {
    constructor(props){
        ({isvalid: this.isvalid, ...this.iProps} = props);
    }
}
console.log(new Example({isvalid: false, a: 42, b: "example"}));
```

Comment: So, every time I want to use {} in statement I must wrap it in parenthesis?

Comment: @PrafullDhadkar - If the `{` is at the beginning of the statement, yes. Otherwise, it starts a block. This isn't true when the parser expects an *expression* (`a = {}`), but it's true when the parser is expecting either an expression or a statement. The `()` tell the parser you're using an expression rather than starting a block.

Comment: The `...this.iProps` bit is very interesting. Only seen variables used *collect* the remaining properties. Never property accessors. So, `({ key, ...this.a.b.c } = obj)` is `this.a.b.c = objButWithoutKey`

Comment: @adiga - Right, plus `key = obj.key;`. The target in a destructuring expression (`{source: target}`, or `[target]` for iterable destructuring) can be any assignable thing, including an object property.